# My Node.js local application won't connect to Azure SQL DB

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-sql-database, sequelize.js

I am developing a Node.js-Express-EJS web application, with Azure SQL DB (cloud version of MS SQL Server).

I try to test my connection first on the remote Azure SQL DB, using SQL Server Management Studio. First, I set my machine's IP to be allowed in Azure SQL DB firewall rules. Then I was able to get into the database, create and populate table, and query using the Management Studio.

Now, I have the Node.js app locally first. However, it seems it can't connect to the remote Azure SQL DB using same credentials.

First, I use the tutorial in node-mssql:

```
/* Using node-mssql */
var sql = require('mssql');

router.get('/test/mssql', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('Testing node-mssql')

    sql.connect("mssql://<username>:<password>@<server>.database.windows.net/<db>")
        .then(function() {

            new sql.Request()
                .query('SELECT * FROM mytable')
                .then(function(recordset) {
                    console.dir(recordset);
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });


        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

I was only able to get from the console

```
'Testing node-mssql'
GET /contact/test/mssql  - - ms - -
```

But no response, it seems its waiting forever, it didn't even throw error.

Same thing happens when I use Sequelize.js

```
/* Using Sequelize.js */
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('<db>', '<username>', '<password>', {
  host: '<mydb>.database.windows.net',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },

});

router.get('/test/sequelize', function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('Testing sequelize');

    sequelize.authenticate()
        .then(function(err) {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
        });
});
```

Result:

```
Testing sequelize
GET /test/sequelize - - ms - -
```

Here are the versions that I am using:

```
Node.js - 4.6.0
express - 4.14.0
mssql - 3.3.0
sequelize - 3.30.2
tedious - 1.14.0
```

(I wonder if this has to do with me connected on WiFi? But impossible, bec. Management Studio works fine right?)

Comment: First thing to check with SQL Azure and connection issues is that the firewall is open up to the ip address of the client.

Comment: @MikeS That's what I did. My Management Studio connection to Azure SQL DB is working. On same machine as I launch my Node.js app.

Comment: Did you try supplying the port number in the code?

Comment: Also, see if the same code can connect to a local instance of Sql server.

Comment: @MikeS Same thing happens when I supply the port 1433 to connection string or config.

Comment: And if you try connecting to a local instance? Same thing? I am not familiar with these node.js libraries so beyond those ideas, that's as far as I can help with connectivity issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying it out with Azure SQL Database, you'd need to add `?encrypt=true` to your connection string that will look like:

```
mssql://<username>:<password>@<server>.database.windows.net/<db>?encrypt=true
```

For *Sequelize.js*, you'd need this: `dialectOptions: { encrypt: true }`. The code will look like:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('<db>', '<username>', '<password>', {
  host: '<mydb>.database.windows.net',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
  dialectOptions: { 
    encrypt: true 
  },

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },

});
```

Comment: Sorry, this works on mssql. The same problem occurs on sequelize. Anyway, I've marked your post the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your connection string, as that doesn't look like a SQL Database connection string that would work.

For `mssql`, try connecting like this:

```
var config = {
 server: "<servername>.database.windows.net",
 database: "<dbname>",
 user: "<username>",
 password: "<password>",
 port: 1433,
 options: {
       encrypt: true
   }
};

sql.connect(config).then(function() { ... } )
```

FYI for reference, SQL Database (at least through .net) expects a connection string like this, so you might have success with a similar connection string directly passed to `sql.connect()` (though I haven't tried it):

```
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```